# Easytrieve - Removing leading zero in numeric variable

Tags: mainframe, easytrieve

Using Easytrieve program am trying to fetch the details from DB2. But one off the column is having integer datatype and am moving the data to binary variable.
And I need to perform arithmetic operation in this variable and result will be move to output file.

When i try to move binary value to alpha numeric am getting leading zero.

Not sure how to remove those leading value.

For example :

```
DB2 column name (Period_value) = 240 
Easytrieve : 
FILE TEMP1 
  TEMP-PERIOD     1   5  A 

WS-VAL1    W  4 B 0    
WS-TEMP    W  4 N 

.... 
....
```

using cursor to get the value from Db2

WS-VAL1 is holding the value 240

```
DISPLAY  WS-VAL1                  => OUTPUT : 240 

* CALCULATION

WS-VAL1 = WS-VAL1 + 1 

WS-TEMP = WS-VAL1

DISPLAY WS-TEMP         ->  OUTPUT : 0241 

MOVE  WS-TEMP to TEMP-PERIOD

PUT TEMP1
```

But output file contains

```
0241 

Expected output 
241 
242 (without leading zero)
```

Could someone help me on this.

Comment: Did you mean Rexx? In any case, this is an easytrieve problem - the data was returned from DB2 OK - so the tags Rex, DB2 and COBOL are wrong and should be removed. I assume that easytrieve supports the Z PIC character that says "do not display this position if it is zero" (it will be a space). The Z can be leading character only - you cannot have 9Z9,

Comment: In easytrieve the supported data type are (A,N,B,P). So i believe Z can't used. 
 [Click here](http://code.xmlgadgets.com/2009/10/07/easytrieve-variable-declaration/)

Comment: Try adding  MASK 'ZZZZZZZ9'.  to its definition